# Loading an sql file from within PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can i import *.sql in mysql database using php 
how can i do this please help me to fix this issue thanks

here's my code :

```
if (mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''))
{
    print_success("Connection &agrave; la base de donn&eacute;e r&eacute;ussie.")   ;
}
else print_error(mysql_error()) ; 

mysql_query(" CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ".$_SESSION['dbname']." DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci ; ") or print_error(mysql_error()) ; 


// Création du User/Password
$_SESSION['dbuser'] = "user".$_SESSION['subdomain'];
$_SESSION['dbpassword'] = substr(md5($_SESSION['subdomain'].$_SESSION['subdomain']),0,12);

@mysql_query(" DROP USER ".$_SESSION['dbuser']." ; ") ;  
mysql_query(" CREATE USER ".$_SESSION['dbuser']." IDENTIFIED BY '".$_SESSION['dbpassword']."'; ") or print_error(mysql_error()) ; 

if(WEBSERVER) mysql_query(" GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ".$_SESSION['dbname'].".* TO '".$_SESSION['dbuser']."'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '".$_SESSION['dbpassword']."' ; ") or print_error(mysql_error()) ; 
else mysql_query(" GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ".$_SESSION['dbname'].".* TO '".$_SESSION['dbuser']."'@'10.0.66.%' IDENTIFIED BY '".$_SESSION['dbpassword']."' ; ") or print_error(mysql_error()) ;

$sqlFile = "Database.sql";
$command='mysql -h localhost -u root ".$_SESSION['dbname']." < ' .$sqlFile;
```

It create an empty database, and dump the sql file at the current database which duplicate items!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, your `$_SESSION['dbname']` should be set to the database you want to execute the dump on.

However, assuming this is correct (which I do assume, because the script creates the empty DB), please check your .sql file to make sure that it isn't creating or using a database (`USE xyz` or `CREATE DATABASE xyz`) inside that file.

As an edit, I would like to request the Database.sql file to confirm that it is not switching DBs. Of course, please edit out sensitive information if you do fulfill this request.